# What is the equivalent function of ccp() on cocos2dx version 3.2

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am currently to development a game which is also can be seen on the tutorial on this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/33752/cocos2d-x-tutorial-for-ios-and-android-space-game

As I follow this tutorial, I encountered a problem on implementing the codes for adding child nodes on my ParallaxNode. My problem is... In the given tutorial, he used the statement: _backgroundNode->addChild(_spacedust1, 0, dustSpeed,  ccp(winSize.height/2)); to add child on his parralaxnode.  what I want to know is the equivalent ccp() function on cocos2dx version 3.2. because when I am trying to compile the game application, there are errors that are showing up.

Comment: ccp() is a macro for the CCPointMake function, so if you cant locate this macro you cant use it. Try CCPointMake instead

Answer (score 7):

`CCPointMake` or `ccp` is deprecated now and instead use `Vec2` like:

`Vec2(x, y)` is equivalent of `ccp(x, y)`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @ user503413 this is answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Anyway if you use _backgroundNode->addChild(_spacedust1, 0, dustSpeed, ccp(winSize.height/2)); then this can't compile due incorrect syntax.

You have only one input in your code *ccp(winSize.height/2)* ccp, Point, Vec2 need two inputs x and y. Use Vec2(x,y) and will compile.